# Take print with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have developed JSF + Primefaces application, Working fine on LAN network

Now I want to shift my application over the cloud, When it comes on printing reports [automatically, without generating in PDF using jasper], currently, at  server end, application is printing configured with server using `PrinterJob` in core java.

Yes client computer must have printer configured.
I would like to include JavaScript [if possible] for this job, I have list and variable loaded on web page.

I couldn't find anything related to that

Comment: You just can't. Try from plain html and if that works (it won't), you could try to extrapolate to jsf. https://www.google.nl/search?q=print+directly+from+javascript

Comment: So, If i can't do that, other thing in my mind comes is another client server application in java which will be running / installed on client machine to take print. Like a thread it will wait queued jobs to print. How about that?